# Why does Selenium still ask me to configure Saves when I have it set in Python already?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm not really a Python user, but I'm using some code that I got online to download a file. One of the code is:

```
        urlpage = 'https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/' + '10100127' + '-eng.zip'
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'D:\downloads')
        profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(urlpage)
```

Which from what I can see, should just download the file to my D: drive in the downloads folder, yet when I run the code, the webpage opens and then asks me if I would like to either view or download the file. Is there anything wrong with the code? or am I doing something wrong?

Not sure if it's important information, but I'm using PyCharm as my IDE

Comment: they change so many elements in web browsers so finally some elements don't work.

Comment: you are not using the prefs while creating driver in this line `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: @supputuri how do I use it then? I've never really used Python, and I assumed that's when you're setting the profile

Comment: let me check and post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script that you should use, this will save the file in system default downloads folder.

```
FF_options = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
FF_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip")
driver= webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=FF_options)
```

If you want to save the downloaded file in specific location then add the below prefs.

```
# change the path here, current line will save in the working directory meaning 
# the location where your script is.
FF_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd()) 
FF_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
```

Comment: btw make sure the download content type matches with the one specified in `saveToDisk` line above. I just specified generic `application/zip`. Let me know if you need help if finding the content-type.

Comment: Check and let me know how it goes.

Comment: will check in the future, i've been told to try it out in chromium